# Как лучше сделать задержку v-if на vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, frontend, vuex

Всем привет

Vue проект. Задача стоит - скрывать сайдбар по клику. Я сделал по типу hideSidebar = !hideSidebar. И при клике, часть элементов должны скрываться, а сам сайдбар становиться уже. Все работает хорошо, но вот когда я тыкаю кнопку чтобы открыть его обратно - элементы резко появляются, и в то время пока сайдбар разъезжается обратно по ширине его колбасит из-за того что элементам тесно пока он не наберет свою ширину. Я хочу чтобы эти элементы не сразу появились, а когда сайдбар уже станет широким, для этого использую . Но тыкать по файлу во всех местах где это надо - засорять файл одним и тем же кодом.

Отсюда вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы разово прописать, например, родителю, , внутри которого все v-if примут его значения?

Answer (score 0):

### Лучше ограничиться решением с помощью CSS.

Вам стоит добавить еще одну обёртку(sidebar__inner) для элементов и сделать её фиксированной.
Контейнер(sidebar) должен иметь свойство overflow: hidden;

```
<div class="sidebar"> <!-- ширина меняется -->
  <div class="sidebar__inner"> <!-- фиксированная ширина width: 300px -->
    <div class="sidebar__item"></div>
    <div class="sidebar__item"></div>
    <div class="sidebar__item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```